# PC not turning on after being unplugged overnight

Tags: boot

So i have this PC set up where every first boot of each day fails. The ez debug led cpu turns on, off for a sec, and turns on permanently. Gpu fans stopped spinning as well. I force shut down my system, unplug, wait for 5 mins, try again and it works perfectly after 1 to 3 tries.

I kept track of the times that my PC is failing to boot and turns out that the problem only arises when unplugged overnight. I tried turning it on early in the morning and after successfully booting, i turned it off and waited 10 hours that same day before booting again. Result: pc boots perfectly fine. I turned it off after using and waited another 10 hours. The next day, i tried booting it and it fails once again.

Any insights or solutions on how to fix this? I tried updating bios and clearing cmos battery. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Specs:
b450m mortar max
Ryzen 5 2600
MSI rx 580 8gb
PNY xlr8 8x2 3200 mhz

Comment: Look up the manual for your computer or mainboard to learn what patterns in the EZ Debug LED mean. This will likely tell you what is wrong, or at least give you more information to learn what your mainboard thinks the problem is.

Comment: It just says that the cpu is either undetected or failed. But then i think that's impossible because when i have successfully booted it, there seems to be no any kind of error even in max loads

Comment: Open the case and the PSU case.  Look for Electrolytic Capacitors that may be bulging or leaking (crud at the base of the capacitor).  The symptom you describe could be a capacitor gone bad and not recovering well enough without power for the night.

Comment: Whatever the case it's a hardware fault and you're really best off taking it to a local PC tech to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Will, do. I'll update soon. Thank you for all the comments!